# what's the exact way to get the position of an element?

Tags: javascript, html

related to browser window's upper left corner of client area.

Comment: My mistake on the duplicate flag. Thought I saw a jQuery tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: That's the right idea, but I believe there are some browser inconsistencies in the way `element.offsetParent` and `element.offsetTop`/`element.offsetLeft` is handled. I'd research how the major frameworks the doing this before copy/pasting that code...

Comment: Actually quirksmode has been dealing with cross browser compatibility for years but if you can use Jquery (or part of it) take a look at the offset method http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset

Comment: Indeed. The jQuery implementation is pretty hairy:  http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/jquery/src/offset.js Prototype's `Element.viewportOffset()` may be worth looking at as well http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js